# how to find if page is reloaded/refreshed or navigated in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-events

I have to find whether a page is refreshed or it is loaded because of some routing.

I think it's possible using Angular `Router`'s `NavigationEnd` event by `subscribe`ing to the router events.

Anyone knows how to do it?

No pure javascript solutions, please.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, you can use it like this:

1. You can listen to [**`events`**](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#events) Observable on the [**`Router`**](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) instance.
2. It is going to fire with a lot of events. So you might want to filter out the unnecessary events and only use the event type that you're interested in, i.e. [**`NavigationEnd`**](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd). You can achieve it using Rxjs's [**`filter`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator.
3. On subscribing to `NavigationEnd`, you will get an event object which would be of type [**`NavigationEnd`**](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd). This has properties like [**`urlAfterRedirects`**](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd#urlAfterRedirects) and [**`url`**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent#url) that you can leverage to understand if the routing action resulted in navigation to a particular component.
4. In case of a refresh/reload, the `NavigationEnd` event won't fire. So if that fires, you can be sure that it was a situation of a page being routed into.

Something along the lines of this:

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    ..., private router: Router, ...
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...

    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      )
      .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        console.log('Got the Event URL as ', event.url);
        if(event.urlAfterRedirects.includes('project')) {
          console.log('This was redirected to the Project Component');
        }
      });
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uri-encode-activated-route-param?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproject%2Fproject.component.ts) for your ref.

**PS:** To confirm on the 4th point, just try pressing the reload button on the StackBlitz's [**View Mode**](https://angular-uri-encode-activated-route-param.stackblitz.io/project/R%2526D%2520Some%2520Other%2520Text) and then check if anything gets printed on the console. Since this a reload, nothing will get printed. This can be considered as a certainty for a refresh/reload situation.

Comment: But how do I know if its a Refresh/Reload or page is being routed into?

Comment: @Jocket, try the updated answer. Check on the **4th point** and the **PS** and hopefully it should be clear to you. :)

Answer (score 2):

**In App.component.ts**

```
subscription: Subscription;
pageReloading: boolean = false;

constructor(private router: Router){
    this.subscription = router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          this.pageReloading = !router.navigated;
          console.log(this.pageReloading)
        }
    });
}
```